# Compare items in vectors

Tags: c++

I have two string vectors,

```
std::vector<std::string> tasks;
std::vector<std::string> completedTasks;
```

tasks will have items like,
`task1`, `task2`, `task3`

completedTasks will have items like,
`task2`, `task4`

I want to check each and every task with each `completedTask`, if both matches then return `true`.

For example `task1` from `tasks` vector will be compared with items in `completedTasks` vector. since it won't match with any items in `completedTasks`, should return `false`. `task2` will match with item in `completedTasks` vector, so need to return `true`.

http://cpp.sh/9ggr

Can we do with `find_if`?

Comment: Are both lists sorted in the same order?

Comment: You could use find_if with a function like return currentTask==currentCompletedTask

Comment: Hmm, maybe tasks == completedTasks do this. But std::mismatch definitely do.

Comment: you can use find_if in several ways. that is not what I am intrested in.
use std::set (which is automatically sorted) at least for 'competedTasks' instaed of std::vector so you can check the existence in log2(n) time complexity instead of n.

Comment: Perhaps you might use `std::set<string>`

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the vectors for equality! No need for algorithms or anything complicated.

```
const bool the_same = (tasks == completedTasks);
```

`std::vector<>::operator==` compares the operands' sizes, then compares each operands' elements in order.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: I think the OP meant if any one entry in the vectors matches, true needs to be returned!

Comment: @Garg: _"I want to check each and every task with each completedTask, if both matches then return true."_ You can only "return true" once so if the OP meant what you said then they have to be much clearer.

Comment: yeah. Let's wait for @Nic to clear what he wants. ;)

Comment: if taks size is 1 and completedTasks size is 2 then it returning false. this is not expected.

Comment: @Nic: Yes it is. You need to better explain what your goal is, then. The question is extremely ambiguous.

Comment: I have updated my question. hope it will clear my requirement. both vectors can have any number of items, ofcourse the vector sizes are not same.

Comment: @Nic: Nope, still very unclear. How can the containers contain the same elements if they contain different numbers of elements? And if they contain different numbers of elements, which ones would you like to individually compare? You need to state your requirements precisely and scientifically, preferably with multiple examples covering all the corner cases.

Comment: why two different vectors cannot have same element? this is just string value.

Comment: @Nic: Mate what.................... How can a vector "a","b","c" have the same values as a vector "a","c"? What does that _mean_? There's one missing!

Comment: @Nic I see, at least two-fold ambiguity in your question: **1.** Either check if all tasks are done (already answered by @Lightness Races in Orbit) or **2.** Check which of the tasks is done (`return true`) and which is not done (`return false`) (for which you'll need 2 nested `for` loops to run and compare each of the elements of the two vectors). **Which one is it 1, 2 or something else?**

Comment: I give up.​​​​​ You're not listening to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the non-member `operator==`, as in:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
bool operator==(vector<T, A>& lhs, vector<T, A>& rhs);
```

Then do `completedTasks == tasks`

Or use `std::equal` (checking sizes are equal first):

```
tasks.size() == completedTasks.size() &&
    std::equal(tasks.begin(), tasks.end(), completedTasks.begin());
```

Note the above option is a possible way of implementing `operator==`, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Let me intoduce you better way to achieve it using `set::set<std::string>`:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> tasks;
    set<string> completed;

    tasks.push_back("task1");
    tasks.push_back("task2");
    tasks.push_back("task3");
    tasks.push_back("task4");

    completed.insert("task2");
    completed.insert("task3");

    // write all completed tasks
    for(set<string>::iterator it=completed.begin(); it!=completed.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " is completed, sir!\n";
    }

    // check if task3 is completed
    if(completed.find("task1") != completed.end()) cout << "#1 is completed\n";
    else cout << "#1 is not completed\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/dvgGAH

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am trying,

But without for loop,

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++)
{
    if (std::find(completedTasks.begin(), completedTasks.end(), tasks[i]) != completedTasks.end())
    {
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Check my answer and its live demo, @Nic :)

Comment: If you need to check each value, you can't do it without loop.

Comment: Yet you can replace for with for_each or while for example